# How to insert several lines batch SQL? { UNIDAC/FIREBIRD]

Tags: batch-file, firebird2.5, firedac, unidac

how insert multiple lines SQL/batch in UNIDAC equal to FIREDAC?
Firedac example:

```
FDQuery.ParamByName ('NAME') AsStrings [0] = 'MARIA';
FDQuery.ParamByName ('NAME') AsStrings [1]: = 'JOHN';
FDQuery.ParamByName ('NAME') AsStrings [2]: = 'JOSSE';
FDQuery.Execute (3,0);
```

Comment: Please remember tgat SO isn't a code writing service; so provide what you have tried and, if problems arise, ask a specific question... thanks!

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. You mark a question as resolved by accepting an answer (in this case your own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature only in the latest version of Unidac, see also:

http://blog.devart.com/using-batch-operations-in-delphi-data-access-components.html